# How to temporarily make gq consider hyphen (-) a normal word, to not indent the following lines in the same paragraph

Tags: indentation, formatting

I have tried this in a JavaScript file after disabling `smartindent` and `autoindent` options, with `textwidth = 80`, but it is still the same.
It also happens automatically because of the `textwidth` option when inserting words which together have a length of over 80 characters.

**What happens:**

```
/**
 * - a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l
 *   m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
 */
```

**What I want:**

```
/**
 * - a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l
 * m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
 */
```

Thank you very much! `:-)`

Comment: As near as I can figure out, there is no way to disable the automatic list formatting, but the formatting code in the Vim source is somewhat confusing, so I may be wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim's default Javascript configuration contains a setting to [format dashed lists in comments](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/1c57fe8b9450eb29c3e42a94527d4b7514f853e2/runtime/ftplugin/javascript.vim#L25):

```
setlocal comments=sO:*\ -,mO:*\ \ ,exO:*/,s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://
```

To get the behaviour you want, simply override the setting (for javascript filetypes) to leave out the dashed list part:

```
setlocal comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://
```